# How to use tkinter with functions and their variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to press the start button to store "Hello" in a variable that can be used by other functions. Then, I want to press the print button to print it.

```
import tkinter

FONT = "Arial 16 bold"

window = tkinter.Tk()
B = tkinter.StringVar()

def main() :

    window.title("print")
    window.configure(bg="white")
    startButton = tkinter.Button(window, bg="white", font=FONT, text="START", command=myList)
    startButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
    printButton = tkinter.Button(window, bg="white", font=FONT, text="Print", command=printList)
    printButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

    tkinter.mainloop()

def myList():
    A = "Hello"
    global B 
    B.set(A)

def printList():

    value = B.get()
    printLabel = tkinter.Label(window, bg="white", font=FONT, textvariable=value)
    printLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

main()
```

I don't know how to store the variable in a way that can be used by other functions.

Comment: In your function `myList` you already know how to declare `global` - simply apply the same logic to any variables you need. Or better yet, make a `class` and store your variables as class attributes.

Comment: So why doesn’t my printList() work?

Comment: Because 1. You didn't declare `global B` in your `printList` function, and 2. you used `value` as a textvariable for your label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is these two lines of code:

```
value = B.get()
printLabel = tkinter.Label(window, bg="white", font=FONT, textvariable=value)
```

You are setting the value of the `textvariable` option to a normal python variable. That won't work, it needs to be one of the special tkinter variables.

If all you're doing is displaying the value inside `B`, there's no need to do anything other than set the `textvariable`. You don't need to call `B.get()` or declare `B` as global:

```
def printList():
    printLabel = tkinter.Label(window, bg="white", font=FONT, textvariable=B)
    printLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

If you don't want them to be linked in this way, then you can get the value of `B` and assign it to the `text` attribute rather than `textvariable` attribute:

```
def printList():
    value = B.get()
    printLabel = tkinter.Label(window, bg="white", font=FONT, text=value)
    printLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
```